# How to pass imported value in CloudFormation user data

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am importing an AZ name from another stack and want to pass it through the userdata of a Launchconfig. The reason is to be able to run a cron job differently depending on the AZ of the instance. I have tried all kinds of combinations but cannot  make it work

Here is the code from the files section of CloudFormation::Init

```
Metadata:
AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
config:
 packages:
  yum:
   httpd: []
 files:
  /home/ec2-user/cronsetup.sh:
   content: !Sub |
    #!/bin/bash
    instanceaz=`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone`
    subnetaz=Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${NetworkStackName}-PublicAZ1

    if [[ "instanceaz" == "subnetaz" ]]
    then
     echo "15 * * * * /home/ec2-user/script.sh" >> /var/spool/cron/ec2-user
    else
     echo "30 * * * * /home/ec2-user/script.sh" >> /var/spool/cron/ec2-user
    fi
```

This is the output of the file where s1=NetworkStackName -

```
subnetaz=Fn::ImportValue: !Sub s1-PublicAZ1
```

and what I would like to see is `subnetaz=us-west-2a`

I have also tried:

```
subnetaz=[${x},x: Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${NetworkStackName}-PublicAZ1]
```

but this gives a template format error.

Comment: Can you try this 
`Fn::ImportValue:
  !Sub "${NetworkStackName}-PublicAZ1"`

Mind the quotes and indentation. Ref : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html

Comment: I changed the template to - instanceaz=`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone`
        subnetaz=Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${NetworkStackName}-PublicAZ1"

Comment: I changed the template to -                                                     instanceaz=`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone`
subnetaz=Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${NetworkStackName}-PublicAZ1"  , but got similar result                                               subnetaz=Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "s1-PublicAZ1"